# R; The number of days maximum and minimum in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have dataframe and I want to have two new columns nmaxa and nmina showing for how many days column a is at a maximum and another column showing for how many days  column a is at a minimum. If it is not a max or min then the number of days would be 0. The number of lookback days for which is a maximum or minimum could be very large.   I have tried to find a lookback function in R to do this but I was unable to find one.

```
 set.seed(123)
 days = 1:100
a = runif(100, 1, 100)


df <- data.frame(days,a)
head(df)
tail(df)
```

Examples:
If the value if column a is greater than both the previous last 2 days but less than the previous day 3 then the returned value would be 2.

If the value if column a is less than the previous last 3 days but greater than the previous day 4 then the returned value would be 3.

This is a specific example  but I need it to look as far back until the max or min condition is no longer met (do while conditional loop) and return the number of days which is a maximum and minimum.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the post to make it more clear what I need to do. This is a toy example, but the variable lookback period for the min and max could be very large

Comment: Can you check this logic `head(df) %>% mutate(a1 = lag(a, default = first(a)), a2 = lag(a, 2, default = first(a)), new  = a > a1 & a > a2 & a < lag(a, 3, default = first(a)))`

Comment: Or it would be a rolling function with `rollapply`

Comment: Is column b needed in the example?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. The rollapply function specifies a fixed lookback window. In this case it is unknown and increments back until the condition is no longer in place.

Comment: You are right column b is not needed and I have removed it.

Comment: @adam.888 Based on your updated logic, I posted a solution.  Can you please check. thaks

Comment: It is a very elegant solution to the above specific example but I need it to look as far back until the max or min condition is no longer met.

Comment: hi what is the desired output for the `head` of your dataset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yet another `data.table` option using self join with the `mult=` argument:

```
df[, nmaxa :=  .SD[.SD, on=.(days<days, a>=a), mult="last", 
    i.days - fcoalesce(x.days, 0L) - 1L]
]

df[, nmina := .SD[.SD, on=.(days<days, a<=a), mult="last", 
    i.days - fcoalesce(x.days, 0L) - 1L]
]
```

output of `head(df, 18L)`:

```
     days         a nmaxa nmina
  1:    1 29.470174     0     0
  2:    2 79.042208     1     0
  3:    3 41.488715     0     1
  4:    4 88.418723     3     0
  5:    5 94.106261     4     0
  6:    6  5.510093     0     5
  7:    7 53.282443     1     0
  8:    8 89.349485     2     0
  9:    9 55.592066     0     1
 10:   10 46.204859     0     3
 11:   11 95.726501    10     0
 12:   12 45.880081     0     5
 13:   13 68.079493     1     0
 14:   14 57.690707     0     1
 15:   15 11.189544     0     8
 16:   16 90.082672     4     0
 17:   17 25.362686     0     1
 18:   18  5.163894     0    17
```

Answer (score 4):

May be this would work

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Max := (Reduce(`&`, lapply(shift(a, n = 1:2, 
   fill = first(a)), `<`, a)) & a < shift(a, n = 3, fill = first(a))) * 2]
df[, Min := (Reduce(`&`, lapply(shift(a, n = 1:3, 
   fill = first(a)), `>`, a)) & a > shift(a, n = 4, fill = first(a))) * 3]
```

Comment: @MacOS Except for the `shift` part, all the other functions are from `base R`.  So, it is easier to construct a shift with `embed`